# SSRS Subscription Failure

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence, subscription

This is hopefully a simple yes/no question but I cant find anything definitive online.

If an SSRS subscription - on a once a day schedule - fails because a data source is deleted, if you rebuild the data source will the subscription run as normal the following day or do you need to alter the subscription to rebuild it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you Sébastien Sevrin and Mmcgowa3. That was what I had hoped, we have 100's of reports which run subscriptions and I needed to point them all at a different database.

I created the new data source and pointed the reports at it but my boss told me he wanted me to go and alter each subscription schedule by 1 minute or else they wouldn't fire but that sounded silly to me.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you rebuild the data source will the subscription run as normal the
>   following day or do you need to alter the subscription to rebuild it?

Short answers: **No** and **No**

---

**First No**

If the datasource has been deleted and you recreate it, then the `DataSourceID` property will be different.

So all the dependent items will have first to be "re-linked" to the datasource (reports, shared datasets).

**Second No**

Nothing will have to be changed in the Subscription though, because the Subscription is linked to a Report (or Linked Report), so once everything else is valid it will run as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a regular subscription and not a data driven subscription, as long as the published report's data source is set after the new data source was re-created. The subscription should work.